# Index users not configured, Neo4j Batch importer 2.0 error

Tags: batch-file, csv, neo4j, export-to-csv, graph-databases

I have downloaded Neo4j Community 2.0.0 edition for Windows and zip (CSV) Batch Importer 2.0.
I'm trying to import csv files to Neo4j db. For now I'm using just nodes2.csv without relations.

I' m using these samples:

**nodes2.csv**

```
name:string:users    age works_on
Michael 37  neo4j
Selina  14
Rana    6
Selma   4
```

**batch.properties**

```
dump_configuration=false
cache_type=none
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=5M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=5M
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=200M
batch_import.node_index.users=exact
```

I have executed like this:

```
C:\Users\X\Desktop\batch_importer_20>import.bat C:\Users\X\Documents\Neo4j\test.db  sample\nodes2.csv
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index users not configured.
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importNodes(Importer.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:228)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:83)
```

Comment: There is a double space in your commandline?

What else does it output?

Comment: @MichaelHunger In real case there is no double space. It just print's that `Index users not configured.` error and prints that 0 nodes has been imported.

Comment: Can you try it with an empty rels.csv file that only has an header?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I have tried to add rels.csv and it works like you said, but only in case if I omit ":users" from header in nodes2.csv. I think if I omit ":users" from header then there will be no auto-indexing, cause prop `batch_import.node_index.users=exact` in batch.properties depend on it.

Comment: This must be some weird windows, thingy. Did you add a reasonable header to the rels-file?

Comment: Solution. I was putting batch_import.node_index.users=exact into the subdirectory sample instead of main directory where is also file batch.properties.Therefore found no users in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right the batch-importer only looks in the current directory for `batch.properties`.

You can provide a path to a properties file as a first parameter though. That should work too.